# Image resizing on the fly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, thumbnails, image-resizing

For simplicity lets say that I have a web page that needs to display thumbnails of images. The images locations are stored in a database(the images are stored on Amazon S3). Is it possible to have my web server scale down the large image before it is delivered to the client? This way I don't have to store thumbnails of every image and the client can download a smaller file.

Comment: Just to note that the full image will always need to be transferred, the only difference is whom will be pulling it down the wire. That being said, you can implement an `HttpHandler` which could do the image manipulation for you.

Comment: You mention that your images are on S3 - is your application run on a single server or is it a cloud application?  There's a fair overhead to loading up a large image and resizing it that you don't necessarily want if you're running the app on a single server.  You might want to only create a thumbnail if one wasn't already created and then store it on disk so that you don't have to run the code again on the image unless it changes.

Comment: The [ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net) project offers both S3 image resizing and disk caching - it's also widely used and well tested software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, no problem. There's plenty of resources on the web that show how to dish up an image from a database. So I won't duplicate that here.

Once you've loaded the image, you can easily shrink it using .NET. There is an example at the following URL. It doesn't do exactly what you are doing, but it does generate thumbnails of an image.

http://blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graphics/creating-website-thumbnails-in-asp-net

Answer (score 9):

Every tutorial on this topic over-simplifies the situation and nearly **all** of them leak memory. It's a long read, but [you should know about the 29 image resizing pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) so you can avoid them.

I [wrote a library to do server-side dynamic image resizing safely](http://imageresizing.net). It's not something that can be done properly in 1 tutorial or even 10. You can solve 80% of the bugs, but not 100%. And when you're doing something this resource-intensive, you can't tolerate bugs or memory leaks.

The core library is free and open-source, but the Amazon S3 plugin is part of the Performance edition, which has a $249 license fee. The Performance Edition comes with source, examples, and documentation for S3, MS SQL, Azure, MongoDB GridFS, and CloudFront integration, as well as terabyte-scale disk caching and memcaching.

From the statistics I have access to, it appears that imageresizing.net is the most widely-used library of its kind. It runs at least 5 social networks and is used with image collections as large as 20TB. Most large sites use the S3 plugin, as local storage (or even a SAN) isn't very scalable.

Comment: +1 for imageresizing.net - it's full featured, fast, easy to set up, extensible, and affordable.  it'll cost you way more to write your own and it'll be bug-ridden in the end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using `WebImage` class that comes in [`System.Web.Helpers.WebImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) you can achieve this.

You can use this great kid to output resized images on the fly.

Sample code:

```
public void GetPhotoThumbnail(int realtyId, int width, int height)
{
    // Loading photos’ info from database for specific Realty...
    var photos = DocumentSession.Query<File>().Where(f => f.RealtyId == realtyId);

    if (photos.Any())
    {
        var photo = photos.First();

        new WebImage(photo.Path)
            .Resize(width, height, false, true) // Resizing the image to 100x100 px on the fly...
            .Crop(1, 1) // Cropping it to remove 1px border at top and left sides (bug in WebImage)
            .Write();
    }

    // Loading a default photo for realties that don't have a Photo
        new WebImage(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/images/no-photo100x100.png")).Write();
}
```

More about it here: [Resize image on the fly with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.leniel.net/2012/04/resize-img-on-fly-aspnet-webimage.html)

---

Here's a great tutorial that shows how to work with `WebImage` directly from the ASP.NET site:

[Working with Images in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/9-working-with-images)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You make a ASP.Net page that does Response.Clear(), sets Content-Type-header in Response and sends the binary data of the image (also through Response). The image can be resized on-the-fly, but I'd recommend caching it for some time on disk or so. Then you reference the image from HTML as <img src="http://server/yourimagepage.aspx">. For storing image in memory before sending you can use MemStream.

I have sample code but not in front of me right now, sorry. :)